# How to compare wicks

Tags: pine-script

When the lower wick is 2 times longer than the upper wick a bool is supposed to be true but it doesn't do that. the code looks like this
`

```
if(close>open)
    upperTail:=2*(high-close)
    lowerTail:=open-low

if(close<open)
    upperTail:=2*(high-open)
    lowerTail:=close-low

if(lowerTail>upperTail)
    buyAccordingToTails:=true
```

i can see the valuse and even tho the `lowerTail` is more than `upperTail` the bool `buyAccordingToTails` is still false

Comment: it could be because the code rounds the values so that they seem the same or something, when lowertails value is 0.00000000 the code makes buyAccordingToTails true

Comment: Is buyAccordingToTails predefined to True? you wrote nowhere that buyAccordingToTails will be true.

Comment: @ZiurOlpa it is predefined to false, i forgot to add the piece of code in here, it is there.

Comment: @ZiurOlpa wait no, it is there but the code u see has the same conditions but sets it to false. i just had 2 ifs, one made it true but the other made it false. thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

it turns out i just had two if-s, one , made it true and the other made it false and both were doing it at the same time. the code above works